# Cannot find Openshift 3 login details for Eclipse with JBoss tools

Tags: eclipse, authentication, jboss, openshift

Openshift gives a login command for oc upon clicking copy login command but Eclipse asks for a server url and a token.
I tried putting server url and token from the copied command but it shows login error.
It shows **"The server type, credentials, or auth scheme might be incorrect."**
[Openshift login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JWIV.png)

Where can I find these details for login?
Please help me login to openshift using eclipse.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you look at what "Copy Login Command" in the Web-UI for OpenShift gives you you'll see something similar to this:

```
oc login https://192.168.64.39:8443 --token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

There are all informations that you need to connect via Eclipse. You have the server url https://192.168.64.39:8443 and the token that you can give Eclipse when switching the authentication to OAuth.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so MUCH for this straightforward answer! I've been searching all around in the last 45 minutes trying to find the URL to set up my eclipse environment to preview Openshift.